# I have a problem when i try to deploy my app on Vercel. I have this: Error: Command "bundle install" exited with 18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, vercel

I try to deploy my app on vercel, but i have this error:
**Error: Command "bundle install" exited with 18.**

I don't know what is it?

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.4.2
```

plz someone can explain me what is the problem?

I tried to update my bundle, but nothing change.
I tried to delete my BUNDLED WITH in gemfilelock, nothing change.

plz someone can explain me what is the problem? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As at the time of answering this question, Vercel only supports [Ruby versions 2.7.x and 2.5.x](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/ruby#ruby-version). So to resolve this issue, you simply need to update your Gemfile to use `ruby '>= 2.7'` for example